# SQL Pivot data where two columns become one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I would like to have the data from this result in columns instead of rows.
Like : 2011_1 = some value, 2011_2 = somevalue, ...

```
SELECT      
        ls.Year,
        ls.Month, 
        lsq.Quantity
FROM    Log_Sales ls
        INNER JOIN Log_SalesQuantity lsq ON ls.Id = lsq.LogSalesId AND lsq.SaleStatisticTypeId = 1
WHERE   (ls.ProductId = 57983) AND
        (ls.BranchId = 1) AND           
        (ls.Year in (2011,2012,2013))
```

Now i get this result:

```
Year    Month   Quantity
2011    1   9220
2011    2   10211
2011    3   7269
2011    4   7050
2011    5   8543
2011    6   7539
2011    7   6103
2011    8   8905
2011    9   5588
2011    10  5840
2011    11  8041
2011    12  5991
2012    1   11233
2012    2   2829
2012    3   4440
2012    4   7842
2012    5   8557
2012    6   11299
2012    7   10560
2012    8   8350
2012    9   7627
2012    10  9511
2012    11  5293
2012    12  7030
2013    1   6148
2013    2   2774
2013    3   3737
2013    4   2350
2013    5   4016
2013    6   2300
```

When i try using pivot i get as far as this query :

```
SELECT  [1] as '2013_1', [2]as '2013_2', [3]as '2013_3', [4]as '2013_4', [5]as '2013_5', [6]    
as '2013_6', [7]as '2013_7', [8]as '2013_8', [9]as '2013_9', [10]as '2013_10', [11]as '2013_11', 
[12]as '2013_12'
FROM
(SELECT     ls.Month, 
        lsq.Quantity
FROM    Log_Sales ls
        INNER JOIN Log_SalesQuantity lsq ON ls.Id = lsq.LogSalesId AND  
lsq.SaleStatisticTypeId = 1
WHERE   (ls.ProductId = 57983) AND
        (ls.BranchId = 1) AND           
        (ls.Year = 2013) ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
sum(Quantity)
FOR [Month] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
) AS PivotTable;

2013_1   2013_2 2013_3  2013_4  2013_5  2013_6  2013_7  2013_8  2013_9  2013_10 2013_11 2013_12
6148    2774    3737    2350    4016    2300    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

What is already good, but i want to have three years dynamic. Now it's 2011,2012,2013 but next year it will be 2012,2013,2014.

What is the best way to get to this result? Maybe there are other solutions then pivot?
Keep in mind that this part of a large, more complex query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to generate the list of columns so they become dynamic, then pivot using this generated list.

```
    DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX) 
    SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',[' ,'[') + src.[Month] + ']'
    FROM (SELECT      
                cast(ls.Year as varchar)+ cast(ls.Month as varchar) as [Month]
        FROM    Log_Sales ls
                INNER JOIN Log_SalesQuantity lsq ON ls.Id = lsq.LogSalesId AND lsq.SaleStatisticTypeId = 1
        WHERE   (ls.ProductId = 57983) AND
                (ls.BranchId = 1) AND           
                (ls.Year in (2011,2012,2013))) as src
    select @listStr

    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)
    SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT      
                cast(ls.Year as varchar)+cast(ls.Month as varchar) as [Month], 
                lsq.Quantity
        FROM    Log_Sales ls
                INNER JOIN Log_SalesQuantity lsq ON ls.Id = lsq.LogSalesId AND lsq.SaleStatisticTypeId = 1
        WHERE   (ls.ProductId = 57983) AND
                (ls.BranchId = 1) AND           
                (ls.Year in (2011,2012,2013))
    )t
    PIVOT 
    (
    SUM(t.Quantity) FOR [Month]
    IN ('+@listStr+')
    ) pvt'

    Execute(@query)
```

Comment: I'm looking for a result like this but without the dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

I used this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/178733/3) to verify. I added the year column and a dynamic where

```
SELECT year, [1] as 'jan', [2]as 'feb', [3]as 'mrt', [4]as 'apr', 
       [5] as 'may', [6] as 'jun', [7]as 'jul', [8] as 'aug', 
       [9]as 'sep', [10]as 'oct', [11]as 'nov',[12]as 'dec'
FROM
  (SELECT     ls.Month, 
              ls.Quantity,
              ls.Year
   FROM    Log_Sales ls
   WHERE   ls.Year > Year(GetDate()) -3 
   AND     ls.Year <= Year(GetDate())
  ) AS SourceTable
  PIVOT
  (
    sum(Quantity)
    FOR [Month] IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
  ) AS PivotTable
```